# How to prefill the user input form?

Tags: html, google-chrome, autofill

I have a very basic form where I ask user's name, mobile, email. I have enabled autocomplete provision in these fields using the following code:

```
<label for="frmNameA">Name</label>
<input name="name" id="frmNameA" placeholder="Full name" required autocomplete="name">

<label for="frmEmailA">Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="frmEmailA" placeholder="name@example.com" required autocomplete="email">


<label for="frmPhoneNumA">Phone</label>
<input type="tel" name="phone" id="frmPhoneNumA" placeholder="+1-650-450-1212" required autocomplete="tel">
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6h3vLoq0/) is the fiddle. Currently, the user has to focus on these elements and then it displays the suggestions. Is there any way by which we can prefill this data once the form is loaded? We want to prefill the 1st suggestion that comes in the autocomplete and not some hard coded value.

Also, I saw websites like facebook, twitter etc. using only autocomplete and not prefilling the data - is there any specific reason to not prefill the things?

Answer (score 1):

The autocomplete attribute specifies whether a form should have autocomplete on or off.

When autocomplete is on, the browser automatically complete values based on values that the user has entered before.

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get" autocomplete="on">
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You can find the working example on w3schools. here is the link
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_form_autocomplete

Comment: I still need to focus on the input fields and select previously filled values manually. I want to prefill these without user action

Comment: you mean by refreshing the page, all previous values already populated?

Answer (score 0):

You can store user values into the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) at completion, then load this values on page load.

This way, no need to hardcode datas, neither store server side.

```
// Store 
localStorage.setItem("userconfig",mail.value)

// Fill data
onload = (function(){
  mail.value =   localStorage.getItem("userconfig")

})
```

[image]

Comment: I want to pre fill from auto complete - it's not something i want to store first and then populate

Comment: You can't refill automatic. You need javascript for that.